# Titanium: Background image (sized) of the button does not appear correctly when button is clicked

Tags: image, button, titanium, window-resize, click

I have an image.png with dimensions 200x200.
I use it as the background image for a button and I set the button size to 60x60.

The button (and its image) appears correctly as intended when I'm not doing anything to it.

When I click the button, the background image dims (as per normal)

However, the background image (sized) of the button does not appear correctly when button is clicked.

Does anyone know what is wrong and how to make the clicked dimmed image remain the same size?

```
var loginButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
   backgroundImage:'/images/someimage.png',
   height: 200 * 0.3,
   width: 200 * 0.3,
   bottom: 160
   left: 65
});
```

Comment: set this property `backgroundSelectedImage:'/images/someimage.png'` and see if it works for you.

Comment: The thing is i dont have a selected version of the image. I want the selected version to be the same as the non-selected version but just with that default shadow effect.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the same size of backgroundImage as the button. To avoid the resize of background image, your problem may be gone.

Comment: What do you mean by "to avoid the resize of background image"?

Comment: If your button size is in 60x60, use a same size backgroundimage with size 60x60.

Comment: Do you know of a code solution? Using exact sizes is not a solution because it means the size of the app is going to increase sizeably due to all the various resolutions of images needed.